# ionicLoading loader doesn't show

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to display a loader ($ionicLoading) when clicking on a link, but it doesn't show.

html:

```
       ion-slide-box show-pager="true" does-continue="false" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
            <ion-slide ng-repeat="s in sliderPages">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in suggestionList | limitTo:s*sliderItemNumber+sliderItemNumber:s*sliderItemNumber ">
                        <a class="suggestPro" ng-click="sleep(200);launchComputeService(item.id)">
                            <span><img ng-src={{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}} /></span>
                            <p class="flex-caption"> {{item.model}} - {{item.name}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
```

controllers.js:

```
  $scope.sleep = function(milliseconds) {
    console.log("on passe dans sleep")
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Loading...'
    });
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using duration property of $ionicLoading instead of for loop :

```
$ionicLoading.show({
  template: 'Loading...',
  duration: milliseconds
});
```